# How to start background process in Jupyter Lab in Python?

Tags: python, background, jupyter, nohup

I try to start background process in Python in Jupyter Lab, and I:

1. created script "my.py" where I have my code to explore data and saving results to csv file
2. wrote in Terminal of Jupyter Lab: nohup python my.py &
3. wrote path to save results: cd "MyPath/Results"

And what should I do then? Because After above stopes I wrote in terminal: `nohup python my.py &` and I have comunicat that: `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’` and nothing is going on, and when I press enter I have: `[1]+  Exit 2                  nohup python my.py`

How can I start this background process in Jupyter Lab in Python ?